# Kubernetes Solo development environment windows

Tags: windows, development-environment, kubernetes

this project seems to be great to start out with kubernetes on osx https://github.com/TheNewNormal/kube-solo-osx but is there somethign similar for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no windows based Kubernetes dev env.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) to set up a Kubernetes cluster on a Windows machine. It'll create a virtual machine running Linux in which it will set up Kubernetes for you. You can then connect to Kubernetes running in that VM from your Windows environment.

If you want to setup a local Kubernetes cluster with both Linux and Windows-based nodes, have a look at [kubernetes-windows-vagrant](https://github.com/rjmorse/kubernetes-windows-vagrant/), which will use Vagrant t create the VMs and set up the environment for you.